# MVC AspNetUsers compare ID's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to compare an AspnetUser ID with the Registed User ID. I am using this code:

```
 try
        {
            var userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

            var communityId = (from p in context.UserCommunityRole
                               where p.AspNetUsers= userID
                               select p.CommunityID).FirstOrDefault();

            return communityId;

        }
```

But I am getting the follwoing error and Do not understand why:

```
Cannot implicitly converttype 'string'(userID) to Models.AspNetUsers
```

Can any one please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is pretty self explanatory as it's saying that the casting won't be possible cause `userID` is a `string` type and not of type `AspNetUsers`.

Probably you meant to do like below (considering that your `AspNetUsers` entity have a property called `UserID` which is of `string` type)

```
from p in context.UserCommunityRole
where p.AspNetUsers.UserID = userID
```